# Document Views in Content Approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, view, content-approval, modern-document-library

I am a bit confused about the document views that come with content approval: `My submissions` and `Approve/reject Items`.

When I create a new site and turn on content approval on the document library, both views look the same. It is a view grouped on `Approval Status` and nothing else, no filters on the approval status values or on the current user.

Is this correct? If not, how should the views look like?

Comment: I just checked on my SharePoint site & observed same behavior (Note: I am site collection administrator for the site).

Comment: I am a site collection admin too. The Draft Item Security settings we have on the libraries is "Any user who can read items". I wonder if there should be filters in those views or if they are controlled by another mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

After turning on content approval on the document library, the view must be like these:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am also seeing Draft items in both these views. And in 'My submissions' I am not only seeing my submissions, I am seeing all documents for all users. I am site collection admin and the Draft Item Security settings we have on the libraries is "Any user who can read items". Do you suggest I 'repair' the views by adding the correct filters, or are these views controlled by another mechanism?

Comment: It's not recommend to 'repair' the default view, it's not a best practice. You can create a new view as you need.

Comment: Hm. I disabled content approval (these views were removed) and enabled it again and got new views. They do not seem right. 'My submissions' does not just list my submissions, and I am also seeing draft items in both views. The views are just grouped on all Approval status values.

Comment: The official document say that, Approval Status is either in:
Draft (if minor and major versions are enabled) or
Pending (if only the major version is enabled) state

Comment: OK, thanks! We have both minor and major versions enabled. But if the document is in Draft it is usually not up for approval, so I guess that is why I am confused seeing drafts in the approval views,